# Timeline or time function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

In MySQL I can use this select which show timeline view on data in my table/tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(atribute), connection_timestamp 
FROM db 
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(connection_timestamp) 
ORDER BY connection_timestamp ASC;
```

But I need the same timeline view in PostreSQL database too. Can you help me please how I can obtain the same effect? Function DAYOFYER does not exist in PostgreSQL. Thank you for help.

Format would look like:

```
15.10.2014  0
16.10.2014  0
17.10.2014  4
18.10.2014  4
19.10.2014  2
20.10.2014  1
21.10.2014  5
22.10.2014  7
```

After this select:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(connection_timestamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
  COUNT(atribute)
FROM dionaea.connections 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(connection_timestamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
ORDER BY 1;
```

output is messy:

```
  to_char   | count
------------+--------
 01.01.2015 |   5225
 01.08.2014 |   4326
 01.09.2014 |  14509
 01.10.2014 |   2022
 02.01.2015 |   2992
 02.08.2014 |   6064
 02.09.2014 |   9948
 03.01.2015 |   2847
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output to your question. I have no idea what a "timeline view" is supposed to be.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added it.

Comment: What exactly is "messy" about that output? To me this looks exactly the way you want it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need output which is sorted according date (DD.MM.YYYY) 1.1, 2.1 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP "TIMESTAMP")` -- `TIMESTAMP` is a reserved word in Postgres so you'll need to put your conflicting column name in double quotes (better yet -- change it so it does not conflict).

Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

**Edit**

Given the updated question, the query might look like:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(d, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
  cnt
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE(connection_timestamp) d, 
    COUNT(attribute) cnt
  FROM db 
  GROUP BY DATE(connection_timestamp) 
) an_alias
ORDER BY d;
```

PS. Not tested.

Comment: Thanks, so my select will be look as: SELECT COUNT (atribute), connection_timestamp FROM connections GROUP BY EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP connection_timestamp) ORDER BY connection_timestamp;?

Comment: Now that you've shown what you _actually_ need, you'd need to use `to_char(connection_timestamp,'DD.MM.YYYY')`, and you must have that both in the select list and in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @mustaccio, +1, you are correct. They should noy have used `DAYOFYEAR()` for the output they wanted ...

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks! It works, but dates order is messy. I have added output above. What way I can sort it only according dates please?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: @mustaccio PostgreSQL gives this error:
subquery in FROM must have an alias
ROW 4: FROM (
              ^
Recommendation:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

Comment: Then I guess you could do what the _recommendation_ says and add an alias...

Comment: @mustaccio I have tried it, but unsuccessfully :-( I do not know on what place... :-(